# Difference between bootstrap phase and configuration phase in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I am having trouble understanding the difference between bootstrap phase and configuration phase in angular js .
   From the [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2271482&seqNum=3) I understood that there are three phases in angular js :

1. bootstrap phase
2. compilation phase
3. run-time phase 
   But there is no mention of the configuration phase , now in the angular js's site we have the [definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)  of configuration block.
   When this configuration block comes into the picture in bootstrap phase or compilation phase in the angularjs life cycle ???
       I am really confused about the whole phases ... I searched online but didn't get the exact difference between bootstrap and configuration phases .

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661122/2545680)

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Module Loading and Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)